# I am trying to pass data from UITableViewCell to PopUp view and I am using this code to pass data in popup view

Tags: ios, iphone

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]];

    popupController.cornerRadius = 4;
    [popupController presentInViewController:self];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:popupController animated:YES];

    popupController.marray1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.first objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    popupController.marray2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.second objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    popupController.marray3=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.third objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.first objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]);

}
```

Comment: and what is your issue ?

Comment: data is not display in pop up view

Comment: Is this the link to your sample code https://github.com/kevin0571/STPopup  ?

Answer (score 0):

First set the DataValues and then push the screen.

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     STPopupController *popupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]];

    popupController.cornerRadius = 4;
 popupController.marray1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.first objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    popupController.marray2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.second objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    popupController.marray3=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.third objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [popupController presentInViewController:self];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:popupController animated:YES];



    NSLog(@"%@",[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self.first objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]);

}
```

Comment: incompatible pointer type sending 'STPopUpController *' to parameter type of 'UIViewController *' This type of message show  while using this code   [self.navigationController pushViewController:popupController animated:YES];